# Replication from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication, sql-server-2012

I was wondering if there are any problems with having a SQL Server 2012 replication publisher together with some SQL Server 2005 replication subscribers?

Does anybody have some documentation from Microsoft regarding this?

I'm asking because a colleague of mine keeps telling us that it will not work.

Does it also go the other way around? (2012 = Subscriber & 2005 = Publisher)

Thanks
Zarkos

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the type of replication that you're using...

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143699.aspx):

> - A Subscriber to a transactional publication can be any version within    two versions of the Publisher version. For example: a SQL
>     Server 2005    Publisher running can have SQL Server 2012 Subscribers;
>     and a SQL    Server 2012 Publisher can have SQL Server 2005
>     Subscribers.
> - A Subscriber to a merge publication can be any version less than or    equal to the Publisher version.